# Storing authenticated user data with Realm or UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

My app is similar to Twitter where people can make posts and you can follow others to see their posts in your feed. When the user signs in to their account, and the API sends back the user data, I need to store that authenticated user's data.

I already have a Realm `User` class set up, but I use this class to store user data from other users' posts. So my question is, how should I store the authenticated user's data? There are two options I've thought of, but both seem wrong:

1. Create an `AuthenticatedUser` realm class and store it there. I don't think realm supports subclassing other realm classes (in this case my already existing `User` class), so this doesn't seem like the right solution.
2. Store the user's data in `UserDefaults`, but again, this doesn't seem right if I'm already using realm.

What should I do here? What's the best approach to solving this?

Comment: `UserDefaults` is better if the data is not too large, what kind of data are you planning to store?

Comment: Why do you need to store that authenticated users data? When a user authenticates they are a known user to realm so what else do you need to do with that data? What's the use case?

Comment: @Jay Things like their username, display name, profile picture URL, etc.

Comment: Why don't you create a realm called Users which stores UserInfo realm object data, with properties such as display name, profit pic etc? It's a bit unclear what's being asked and what the actual issue is. Can you perhaps clarify the question and explain where you're stuck?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should use Realm to store the user data but not in plain format. Use Encryption supported by Realm. They support AES-256 encryption for stored data. Please see this url: "https://realm.io/products/realm-database/". sub classes needs to be handled separately by storing each and every classes and relationship has to be maintained by us.

User defaults is a big no for storing sensitive information. It is stored in plist in binary format, with no encryption, and is stored in your app’s directory. Please find the details below: "https://www.andyibanez.com/nsuserdefaults-not-for-sensitive-data/"

Hope it helps.